# Calculating Raster Stats inside Polygon?

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon (vector), which represents a very large area, and a raster file which also covers a large area.

Using QGIS I want to calculate what percentage of the vector polygon is covered by the raster file for certain level? Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Install the raster stats plug-in from the plug-in repository. If you need levels of some value in your raster you may need to first reclassify the raster to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the outline of the raster to vector, you could find the overlap and then the overlap areal for calculating areal percentage. The expression editor and field calculator should do this for you.

Not sure about the raster stat plugin doing this percentage for you.